# Laravel - Could not find driver exception with sqlite

Tags: php, laravel, sqlite

I'm using **Laravel** on **Ubuntu 17.4**. When I type this command: `php artisan migrate:refresh` I get the following issue:

> [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
>   could not find driver (SQL: select * from sqlite_master where type = 'table' and name = migrations)
>   [PDOException]
>   could not find driver

I tried to install sqlite driver by running `sudo apt-get install php7.1-sqlite3` but I got the following issue:

> Reading package lists... Done
>   Building dependency tree
>   Reading state information... Done
>   E: Unable to locate package php7.1-sqlite3
>   E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.1-sqlite3'
>   E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.1-sqlite3'.

Also my php version is: `PHP 7.1.5-1+deb.sury.org~yakkety+2`.

Comment: make sure that you've executed the `apt-get update` to update your dependencies.

Answer (score 19):

Are you sure your Sqlite configurations have been set well? Because I had the same issue on my Ubuntu 17.04 and it was solved with

```
sudo apt-get install php7.1-sqlite3
```

Can I know how you configured your sqlite?