# Laravel connection: sqlite, database: memory leads to could not find driver

Tags: laravel, phpunit

I'm running laravel on win10, so I cant really run

sudo apt-get install php7.1-sqlite3 as pointed out here:

[Laravel - Could not find driver exception with sqlite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44344853/laravel-could-not-find-driver-exception-with-sqlite)

I am trying to run some tests with phpunit and inside one of tests I've done:

class ViewConcertListingTest extends TestCase
{
    use DatabaseMigrations;

and inside phpunit.xml

I've added these two

```
    <env name="DB_CONNECTION" value="sqlite"/>
    <env name="DB_DATABASE" value=":memory:"/>
```

What can I do to get laravel to be able to use sqlite and memory database?

Answer (score 0):

Solved by enabling sqlite and sqlite pdo php extensions in php.ini